# in hyperlinkfield, how to query string escape values?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have a Hyperlinkfield in a `GridView` that has `DataNavigateUrlFormatString="blahblah/dostuff.aspx?id={0}"`. But then I hit a case where the field substituted for the {0} has a plus sign in it. It is not escaped for a query string, so now it looks like a space instead of a plus.

I assume similar issues would arise if it would include ampersands, equal-signs or percent-signs.

**Q:** Is there any way to do a query string escape on the parameter?

I guess I could turn it into a `TemplateField` and an `Eval`. At best that's messy and ugly. This seems like an issue that would come up all the time. Is there a clean way to do the escape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of searching I have come to the conclusion that there is no easy solution to this. You can use Eval with no template field to generate the URL directly. Some suggest that you handle the RowDataBound event and find the right column and fix the URL but this seems like extremely ugly solution to me.

The cleanest solution which requires a lot of work is to create a class with the sole purpose to feed the GridView (you can even put it directly in the code behind) and encode the properties in C# code in the code behind. This is like creating a ViewModel in MVC just to feed a specific view.

Comment: I got it to work by using an eval, but it seemed rather round-about and ugly. Using a data-bound event seems even uglier as half the code is in the aspx page and half is in the code-behind, plus, to the best of my knowledge, you have to get the column by number rather than name, which creates a maintenance trap if we later adds a column. I think the final answer is that the way I did it is as good as it's going to get. It's reassuring to know that I'm not doing it a needlessly hard way, but I would have preferred you had just told me some magic function I could call that would do it clean!

Comment: I wish I knew such a function :(